# INSERT has returned affected rows but nothing happens

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, firebird

I am using Database Stored Procedure to insert in my database. It worked ok but since it is new year, we created a new database where everything remains the same but data is deleted. The problem is that the stored procedure is working on the old database but not on the new one.

I have checked tables (old and new) and everything is same. Procedures are also same. When I debug it, it gives me that `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` has affected 61 rows without any error but nothing appears in table.

Why is this happening, what can I do, what to look for?

I have figured out that `executeNonQuery` now gives me `-1`

Here is call of procedure:

```
int selectedRowIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;

DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dataGridView1.Rows[selectedRowIndex];

int robaID = Convert.ToInt16(selectedRow.Cells["ROBAID"].Value);
decimal unesenaKolicina = kolicina.Value;

using (FbConnection con = new FbConnection(connectionString_Baza))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var cmd = new FbCommand("NAPRAVISTAVKU", con)
    {
        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    })
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VRDOK", 33);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BRDOK", brojDokumenta);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ROBAID", robaID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CENA_BEZ_PDV", 0);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KOL", unesenaKolicina);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RABAT", 0);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

And here is procedure itself:

```
SET TERM ^ ;
ALTER PROCEDURE NAPRAVISTAVKU (
    VRDOK smallint,
    BRDOK integer,
    ROBAID integer,
    CENA_BEZ_PDV numeric(15,2),
    KOL numeric(15,3),
    RABAT numeric(15,2) )
RETURNS (
    OK smallint )
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE MAGACINID SMALLINT;
DECLARE VARIABLE MTID VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE VARIABLE NAZIV VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE VARIABLE TARIFAID VARCHAR(3);
DECLARE VARIABLE NABAVNACENA NUMERIC(15, 4);
DECLARE VARIABLE POREZ NUMERIC(15, 2);
BEGIN
  OK = 0;

  SELECT MAGACINID, MTID FROM DOKUMENT
  WHERE VRDOK = :VRDOK AND BRDOK = :BRDOK
  INTO :MAGACINID, :MTID;

  SELECT NAZIV FROM ROBA WHERE ROBAID = :ROBAID
  INTO :NAZIV;

  SELECT NABAVNACENA FROM ROBAUMAGACINU
  WHERE MAGACINID = :MAGACINID AND ROBAID = :ROBAID
  INTO :NABAVNACENA;

  IF (CENA_BEZ_PDV = 0) THEN BEGIN
    SELECT PRODAJNACENA FROM ROBAUMAGACINU
    WHERE MAGACINID = :MAGACINID AND ROBAID = :ROBAID
    INTO :CENA_BEZ_PDV;
  END

  SELECT TARIFAID FROM ROBA WHERE ROBAID = :ROBAID
  INTO TARIFAID;

  SELECT STOPA FROM TARIFE WHERE TARIFAID = :TARIFAID
  INTO :POREZ;

  INSERT INTO STAVKA (VRDOK, BRDOK, MAGACINID, ROBAID, VRSTA, NAZIV, NABCENSAPOR, FAKTURNACENA, NABCENABT,
              TROSKOVI, NABAVNACENA, PRODCENABP, KOREKCIJA, PRODAJNACENA, DEVIZNACENA, DEVPRODCENA, KOLICINA,
              NIVKOL, TARIFAID, IMAPOREZ, POREZ, RABAT, MARZA, TAKSA, AKCIZA, PROSNAB, PRECENA, PRENAB, PROSPROD,
              MTID, PT, TREN_STANJE, POREZ_ULAZ, DEVNABCENA, POREZ_IZ)
  VALUES (:VRDOK, :BRDOK, :MAGACINID, :ROBAID, 1, :NAZIV, 0, 0, 0, 
           0, :NABAVNACENA, :CENA_BEZ_PDV, 0, :CENA_BEZ_PDV, 0, 0, :KOL,
           0, :TARIFAID, 0, :POREZ, :RABAT, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
           :MTID, 'P', 0, 0, 0, :POREZ);

  SUSPEND;

  /* Obrada greske */
  WHEN ANY DO
  BEGIN
    OK = -1;
    SUSPEND;
  END

END^
SET TERM ; ^


GRANT EXECUTE
 ON PROCEDURE NAPRAVISTAVKU TO  "PUBLIC";

GRANT EXECUTE
 ON PROCEDURE NAPRAVISTAVKU TO  SYSDBA;
```

Comment: Did you update your connection string to point at the new DB?

Comment: Yes i did it. Tested it locally and on server

Comment: @juharr i have edited the post. May you please check it now and tell me if anything gets up on your mind

Comment: Remove the `suspend` statements from your stored procedure, your stored procedure should be executable, not selectable.

Comment: What do you mean with _"everything remains the same but data is deleted"_?

Comment: This procedure is working on old DB so i do not think it is not possible. Also it is working on program that my company owns (main program in which we work)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I mean we keep the same form of DB but just empty it.

Comment: @Parpil It depends, in another question you mention using Firebird 1.5 and 2.1; maybe you have upgraded the ODS version of the database by a back up and restore and have introduced an incompatibility that way.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i am now using only 2.1 on my computer, same as on server (where our main program is running ok)

Comment: Let me be more explicit: What was the ODS version of the old database and what is the ODS version of the new database?

Comment: 11.1 - here is image of properties [image](http://image.prntscr.com/image/5e0a1f39b56a4872ab82b3b12ecc2d65.png)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i started selecting manually tables like in procedure and here is what it gives me: image

Answer (score 2):

There are two potential issues that jump to mine when reading this question.

1. Have you updated the connection string in your c#
   application, if not there is a very good chance that you are simply
   running the stored procedure in the old DB.
2. Your stored procedure could be referencing the old DB if
   you've prefixed anything with the old DB name (and both DBs are on the same server). In which case you
   would need to alter your procedure to prefix with your new database name.

The simply way to check for either of these issues would be to query your old DB and see if any of the recent changes you've made have been applied to it. If you see the changes then there is a good chance that one of the above scenarios has occurred.

Comment: How do you mean to query old DB to see changes that have been applied. I am working on DB from our main program we are using, and in that program it is working normally (someone else is creating that program)

Comment: I have edited the post. May you please check it now and tell me if anything gets up on your mind

Comment: Option 2 is not possible with Firebird. Database are self-contained and don't know about the existence of other database, and accessing other databases is only possible with very explicit [`execute statement on external`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-psql-coding.html#fblangref25-psql-execstmt-onexternal) statements.

Comment: This procedure is working on old DB so i do not think it is not possible. Also it is working on program that my company owns (main program in which we work)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes sorry you are correct, not possible in Firebird.

Comment: @Parpil, with regards to checking the old DB I was meaning if your old database still exists could you perform a manual query to look at the changes you expect to happen in the new DB on the old. This will eliminate (or confirm) my initial thoughts that you're referencing the old DB still somewhere. Maybe the 'STAVKA' table where you perform an insert?

Comment: @DanGardner Yap i have the old one. I am checking it by changing my connection string and everything is running ok. I am declaring connection string at first form and then just pass it to others, so there is no manual string input.

Comment: @Parpil I can see that you're saying that `executeNonQuery` method is returning `-1`, is that correct?

Comment: @DanGardner Yea it gives it.

Comment: @DanGardner i started selecting manually tables like in procedure and here is what it gives me: [image](http://image.prntscr.com/image/03e32f7d2919491e96e5784aa70d4ecc.png)

Comment: @Parpil Are you able to run any SQL statements against the DB at all? Does for example a simple select all query execute? I believe a return value of -1 can indicate that the DB rollsback when a procedure is executed, so it would be interest to know if your new DB can execute anything

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Have you looked at that image Parpil just sent? It looks to me that the failure to execute a SELECT with that error could imply a corrupt DB file. Do you agree?

Comment: Thanks guys. I solve it. It is pretty stupid and i do not know why it is happening but i did it. Posting solution in answer.

Comment: @DanGardner Yes, it does. It indicates errors in the file, causes can range from power failures during writes, but also bugs; as far as I know there were some bugs fixed in 2.5

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Ah thanks, that's good to know. Looks like that was the problem anyway Parpil looks to have found it at about the same time! Thanks for the confirmation :)

Comment: @DanGardner "could you perform a manual query to look at the changes you expect to happen in the new DB" starting with Firebird 2.1 there a re monitoring tables so you just can SELECT the actual filename of the database you work in.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was that my DB file was corrupted. While copying it from my Server (through Terminal), somehow my connection get lost for millisecond and because of that file is missing some parts or something. I tried copying it 2-3 more times and after 3rd time, it worked. I do not know if maybe other table is corrupted now but it works with this tables i need.

Comment: You should never copy database files, instead you should backup and restore them.

Comment: Correction: You should never copy database files WHILE SERVER PROGRAM IS RUNNING. It is perfectly okay to shutdown all the firebird server service(s), then to copy the database file(s), and then restart the service(s). Of course if other applications would be okay without server for a while. Suggestion: there are two ways to make a back-up in FB2: GBAK and NBACKUP. Depending on specifics (goals and bottlenecks) of copying - one might be better than another.